# javaCC "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1" exception

Tags: java, exception, grammar, javacc

I have a project in IT studies which is to make a compilator for a simple langage made only for that project (it's a simplified java). To parse the grammar I have made a jjtree file in javacc for a first release (we must use SCRUM method in this project), so it's not with the full grammar yet. At first it seems to work good, and to correctly read what I'm entering. But then, when with the other on the project (we're a group of five) we had to write compilation rule for each visitor that the jjtree generate, we found some problem for rule with multiple choice. We saw that to solve that we have to use tags on the grammar, and that's where we started to have some issue.

I added tag on some rule (especially the one with multiple choice) and now, when we test the parsor, it give us an exception in the declarations of variable. For exemple :

```
class C{
    int i=1;
    main {
       i++;
    }
}
```

It give the exception after the int i=1, when I enter the ";".

```
class C{
    int i[1];
    main {
        i++;
    }
}
```

It give the exception after the second "]" in int i[1]

It give the exception after the int i=1, when I enter the ";".

```
class C{
    int i;
    int x;
    main {
        i++;
    }
}
```

It give the exception when entering the main.

Here's the exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
        at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:418)
        at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:495)
        at JJTGrammaireJavaCCASA2State.closeNodeScope(JJTGrammaireJavaCCASA2State.java:86)
        at GrammaireJavaCCASA2.classe(GrammaireJavaCCASA2.java:50)
        at GrammaireJavaCCASA2.main(GrammaireJavaCCASA2.java:9)
```

Can someone please help me ? I'm new to javaCC and I'm stuck on this for two week. I can't find where there's a problem, and I still have some problems with tags, so it maybe come from here.

Here's the base grammar the teacher gave us (it's in french but I think it's easily understanble even without knowing french) and the one we had rewrite for the javaCC (we use what is in yellow for the Release 1) :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKvQF.jpg

Finally here's the code in javaCC (I deleted the commentary for space and because they're in french, but I can re-add it):

```
options {
    VISITOR = true;
    MULTI=true;
}

PARSER_BEGIN(GrammaireJavaCCASA2)

import java.io.*;


public class GrammaireJavaCCASA2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
        GrammaireJavaCCASA2 parser = new GrammaireJavaCCASA2(System.in);
        SimpleNode root = parser.classe();
        root.dump("");
    }
}

PARSER_END(GrammaireJavaCCASA2)

SKIP : {
      " "
    | "\t"
    | "\n"
    | "\r"
}

TOKEN :{
    <VIRGULE : ",">
    | <PVIRGULE : ";">
    | <PAROUV : "(">
    | <PARFER : ")">
    | <ACCOLOUV: "{">
    | <ACCOLFER: "}">
    | <CROOUV: "[">
    | <CROFER : "]">
    | <PLUS : "+">
    | <MOINS : "-">
    | <MULT : "*">
    | <DIV : "/">
    | <AFFECTATION : "=">
    | <PLUSEGAL : "+=">
    | <INCREMENT : "++">
    | <EGALE : "==">
    | <SUPERIEUR : ">">
    | <DIFFERENT : "!">
    | <ET : "&&">
    | <OU : "||" >
    | <CLASSE : "class">
    | <FINAL  :  "final">
    | <MAIN : "main">
    | <VOID : "void">
    | <RETURN : "return">
    | <IF : "if">
    | <ELSE : "else">
    | <WHILE : "while">
    | <TRUE : "true">
    | <FALSE : "false">
    | <NOMBRE : (["0"-"9"])+>
    | <INT : "int">
    | <BOOLEAN : "boolean">
    | <IDENT : ["a"-"z","A"-"Z"] ( ["a"-"z","A"-"Z","0"-"9"] )*>
}

SimpleNode classe() #CLASSE(3): {}{ 
    <CLASSE> ident() <ACCOLOUV> decls() methmain() <ACCOLFER>{return jjtThis;}
}

void ident() #IDENT: {Token t;}{
    t=<IDENT> {jjtThis.value = t.image;}
}

void decls() #DECLS(2): {}{
    decl() <PVIRGULE> decls() 
    |{} #VNIL 
}

void decl() #DECL(1) : {}{
    vars() 
}

void vars() #VARS(2): {}{
    var() <PVIRGULE> vars() 
    |{} #VNIL
}

void var() #void : {}{
    typemeth() ident() (<CROOUV> exp() <CROFER> #TABLEAU(3)|vexp() #VAR(3))
}

/*void Var2() : {}{
    Vexp()
}*/

void vexp() #AFFECTATIONINIT(1) : {}{
    <AFFECTATION> exp() 
    |{} #OMEGA
}

void methmain() #MAIN(2): {}{
    <MAIN> <ACCOLOUV> vars() instrs() <ACCOLFER> 
}

void instrs() #INSTRS(2): {}{
    instr() <PVIRGULE> instrs() 
    |{} #INIL
}

void instr() #void : {}{
    ident1() (<AFFECTATION> exp() #AFFECTATION(2) 
    |<PLUSEGAL> exp() #SOMME(2)
    |<INCREMENT> #INCREMENT(1))
}


/*void Instr2() : {}{
    <AFFECTATION> Exp()
    |<PLUSEGAL> Exp()
    |<INCREMENT>
}*/

void exp() #EXP1GO(1) : {}{
    exp1()
}

void exp1() #EXP1(1): {}{
    exp2()
}

void exp2() #void : {}{
    <MOINS> terme() [exp2prime()] #NEGATIF(2)
    |terme() [exp2prime()] #TERMEEXP(2)
}

void exp2prime() #void : {}{
    <PLUS> terme() [exp2prime()] #PLUS(2)
    |<MOINS> terme() [exp2prime()] #MOINS(2)
}

void terme() #TERME(2): {}{
    fact() [termeprime()]
}

void termeprime() #void : {}{
    <MULT> fact() [termeprime()] #PRODUIT(2)
    |<DIV> fact() [termeprime()] #DIVISION(2)
}

void fact() #void : {}{
    ident1() #IDENT1GO(1)
    |<TRUE> #VRAI
    |<FALSE> #FAUX
    |<NOMBRE> #NOMBRE
}

void ident1() #IDENT1(1) : {}{
    ident() 
}

void typemeth() #TYPE(1): {}{
    type() 
}

void type() #void : {}{
    <INT> #ENTIER
    |<BOOLEAN> #BOOLEEN
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help, and sorry for my bad english. If you need more information don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following production looks wrong to me

```
void decls() #DECLS(2): {}{
    decl() <PVIRGULE> decls() 
    |{} #VNIL 
}
```

Consider the case where there is no decl.  Then, first, a `VNIL` will be pushed onto the stack and, second, two nodes will be popped off the stack and a `DECL` node will be pushed onto the stack.  So instead of adding one node to the stack as you'd like, it replaces the top node with a `DECL` node.

It would be better to write it this way:

```
void decls() #void : {}{
    (decl() <PVIRGULE> decls()) #DECLS
|
    {} #VNIL 
}
```

Or

```
void decls() #void : {}{ someDecls() | nothing() }

void someDecls() #DECLS : {} { decl() <PVIRGULE> decls() }

void nothing() #VNIL : {} { }
```

A similar comment applies to a number of productions in your grammar.

You could also avoid the use of VNIL like this

```
void decls() #DECLS : {} { decl() ( <PVIRGULE> decl() )* }
```

Bon chance.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll see that with the other poeple on the project to correct the grammar :)
Unfortunately, it didn't solved my problem. But I have solved it myself by removing all number in the tags. Have you an idea why it was crashing the grammar ? I didn't find a good documentation for the tags yet so I don't know exactly how the number work (I was thiking it was the number of child rule)

Comment: Right. It wasn't just the `decls` production. I was just using that as an example.  What `#DECLS(2)` does is pop two nodes from the stack and pushes a new node with those two as children.

Comment: Yeah thanks again, you really helped us ! I followed your advice and correct a number of rule in my grammar and it seems to work now (it read all instruction, I just still have some problems with ast but I almost correcting all of them little by little, and I thinks I should have a good grammar soon :) ).
Thanks for the explanation. I'm still not getting used to them for now, but I'm learning by adding them one by one and see the result